# Second teaching letter vs. letter from a co-advisor from a secondary department for a math positions in LAC

Tags: mathematics, recommendation-letter, job-search, faculty-application, liberal-arts-colleges

When applying for tenure-track positions in mathematics at SLACs, one typically includes one recommendation letter from the math advisor and another as a math teaching letter. However, for the third letter, which would be a better choice: (a) another math teaching letter or (b) a letter from a co-advisor from a different department (which is not STEM)? On one hand, mathematicians may not give as much weight to a letter from a non-mathematician. On the other hand, a co-advisor might be able to provide more personal insights about the applicant compared to a second teaching letter.

Answer (score 0):

I am a professor of mathematics at Denison University, a good liberal arts college in Ohio. I've been on around 10 hiring committees. Based on my experiences, my impression is that **you would be better off with option (a) another math teaching letter**.

To be clear: Denison wants to know that candidates who get hired here will be excellent teachers and will also have a strong scholarly program resulting in several peer reviewed publications in good journals, before tenure. The "non-STEM" comment made me worry that such a letter might be more harmful than helpful, if it somehow triggered the idea that the research program was not solid and serious. Now, if you had said the co-advisor was in STEM, then their letter could help a bit, for the reasons you wrote, but I still think it wouldn't help as much as a letter from another mathematician. Note that **even teaching letters will generally comment a bit on your research skills, service activities, and collegiality**. Furthermore, **most letters from advisors are glowing and don't carry a ton of weight.** That might be even more true of letters from non-STEM advisors, since we don't know their experience supervising math PhD students.

Lastly, I want to point out that **you don't need to limit yourself to three letters**. When I applied to liberal arts jobs in 2014, I had 5 letters. Some places might have restricted to allowing 4. I've certainly read hundreds of files with 4 letters. The key should be to pick people who really know you, know the kind of jobs you're looking for (i.e., can emphasize aspects of your file that make you a good candidate for a job at a liberal arts college), and can write convincingly. For sure, you should only include a teaching letter from someone who has observed you teach. Even better if you've had conversations with them about your goals and development as a teacher. Good luck!